# php file path strange behaviour

Tags: php

I was debugging for long because there was no error shown. The I realise the script is working but the file isn't uploaded to the right folder

my upload.php

```
if ($_POST) {
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/uploaded');
    $img = $_POST['SelectedFile'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
}
```

is located same level with images, and within images there is a folder call uploaded. Strangely the file goes into images but not into uploaded folder.

Comment: `define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/uploaded/');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/uploaded');
```

should be

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/uploaded/');
```

Otherwise your files will go to `images` folder with `uploaded` prefixed to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

try this path:

`./images/uploaded/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$img = $_FILES['SelectedFile']['tmp_name'];
```

instead of

```
 $img = $_POST['SelectedFile'];
```